# Laravel\Symfony Process component fails to start new process

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4, symfony-process

I'm using the Process component provided by Symfony in my Laravel project: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html.

Here is my code:

```
$process = new Process('dir');
try
{
    $process->mustRun();
    print $process->getOutput();
} catch (ProcessFailedException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

So, nothing fancy here, just a cookbook solution. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
The command "dir" failed.
Exit Code: 1(General error)

Output:
================



Error Output:
================
```

I cannot figure out what's the problem since there is nothing in logs. If it matters, I'm running it on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Do you get anything different with any of the following statements: 1) `$process = new Process('dir', null, null, null, 60, ['suppress_errors' => false]);`?  2) `$process = new Process('dir', null, null, null, 60, ['suppress_errors' => false, 'bypass_shell' => false]);`?  3) `$process = new Process('dir'); $process->setEnhanceWindowsCompatibility(false);`?

Comment: @patricus Nothing helped. However, the last (3) method returned no output at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue like @none32 faced. I tried below solution suggested by @patricus and it worked for me.

```
$process->setEnhanceWindowsCompatibility(false);
```